# Using a tablet as a monitor

Tags: display, external-display

I would like to use a tablet (open to any at this point, just want something light) as a monitor as well.

For example using a Nexus 7 as a monitor so I can see the post output of a PC.

Comment: Have you tried this:
http://lifehacker.com/5870378/use-your-ipad-or-android-tablet-as-a-second-monitor-for-your-computer

Comment: Will have to investigate that. Ideally wouldn't need any software as I might want to output something that isn't a PC.

Comment: Without any software? I'd be really surprised you got it working. AFAIK Nexus doesn't have a HW video in. I guess you're locked to SW.

Comment: Not really answering my requirement but this is nice - https://itunes.apple.com/app/duet-display/id935754064