# Use a tablet as a monitor for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, tablet

I'm looking at getting a Raspberry Pi 2 for a project. One of the things I would like to do is use it as a portable machine. Ideally what I'd like to do is use a spare Android tablet that I have lying around, as a monitor for the Pi.

I did see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/511630/using-a-tablet-as-a-monitor) that talks about using a tablet as a monitor, but never had a definitive answer.

The tablet I would use is a Sony Tablet S. Would something like this be possible?

Comment: See if [this link](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-augment-your-computer-with-an-ipad-513479575) is helpful (based on iPad, so not sure how well it would translate to an Android tablet).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I take an HDMI input to my laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/616163/can-i-take-an-hdmi-input-to-my-laptop)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use vnc to mirror through wlan. That's the only viable solution.
[Raspberry PI Wiki on VNC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/)
Need to access a Raspberry Pi, but don't have a monitor spare? ... Start a VNC server